# Can Dataset created in XML be converted to SQL within SSRS? (ReportBuilder)

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder

I have Report Builder on my work laptop and I need to perform testing on a report that connects to an external server. I have challenges dealing with IT departments that sit internally and externally, but manage different aspects of the data. The end game is to modify the report to display a new field which I can then test and the local IT team can import the data onto the local database. I have worked on SSRS before but I am familiar with SQL code in the datasets, not XML as is in this case. The external IT department advises me that I would need software and relevant access to query a "report model (DSV)" as they call it.This would come at a cost and I am wanting a second opinion as to how to deal with this.It seems to me that these data sources are a view of what is in the actual sql database. I can download the RDL into Report Builder and even run the report. There is a Gui that business uses that shows the table/column name of where the new data comes from. So in theory if I could just modify the dataset in the RDL, I could test exactly what I want. The problem is that I know SQL, not XML. A colleague seems sure that there is a way to view the SQL code and not XML. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.  [Icon representing the datasource in Report Builders datasource properties window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by4oi.png)